# Python Requests Login- Login works w/ direct user input but not embedded in variable

Tags: authentication, python-requests

I have some code that log into a website. The first edition of the code used user keystrokes for the username and password i.e.

```
import getpass
username = input("Enter the username: ")
password = getpass.getpass("Enter the password: ")
```

It logs in no problem.

I am trying to alter it such that no user needs to enter the credentials manually and save the credentials instead i.e.

```
username = 'MyName'
password = 'secretPassword123!'
print("Attempting login")
#Inital Login
url = "https://thisurl"
payload = {'user':username,'pass':password,'site_id':'10'}
#Session stores the Session ID Cookie
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post(url, data = payload)
```

The code directly above does not work using the right username and password though. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Are you sure? Have you checked `s.cookies` ?

Comment: what should i look for within the cookies?

Comment: If `s.cookies` contains an authentication cookie.

Comment: I tried to check via `for (name, cookie) in s.cookies.items():
        print (name, cookie)` but nothing printed. How else can I check the cookies?

Comment: That means that you failed to login. Make sure to submit all the form data, and submit them to the correct url (the form 'action')

Comment: the strange thing is, if I key in the password as part of the payload, it will log in and do tasks, if I give the password fixed within the payload post, it doesn't log in. Strange..

Comment: In `payload` you have `password` in quotes, If it's not a typo that's the problem.

Comment: my actual password contains an "!", running it without quotes yields 'invalid syntax', how can I send passwords with punctuation in the payload?

Comment: No, i mean the `'pass'` key in `payload`. It should be `payload = {'user':username,'pass':password,'site_id':'10'}`, no quotes around  `password`

Comment: Suppose my password is `password!`, a message will return saying `invalid syntax`

Comment: In your script you define `password` as `password = 'secretPassword123!'`. In `payload` you have `password` in quotes which means it's a string with the value `"password"`. If you want to use the `password` value (`"secretPassword123"`) don't enclose `password` it in quotes.

Comment: I've edited your code, give it a try.

Comment: i've changed it to refer back to the password variable and now it attempts to log in again. However there is still no authentication cookie, which means it thinks the credentials are wrong (right?). this is most odd!